# String method tutorial in abinit - no output file produced

Tags: openmpi

I'm trying to follow this tutorial in abinit: https://docs.abinit.org/tutorial/paral_images/

When trying to run abinit for any of the tstring files, no output file is produced. For instance, I copy the files tstring_01.in and tstring.files into the subdirectory work_paral_string, edit the tstring.files with the appropriate file names, and run the command mpirun -n 20 abinit < tstring.files > log 2> err.  No error message is shown but also no output is produced. (The expected output file would be tstring_01.out.)

Any suggestions?

Comment: this question is about `abinit` which is not `ab-initio` and very unlikely involves `Open MPI` nor `MPI`

Comment: Okay, sorry about that, there's no abinit tag and I was thinking about the concept of ab initio, not the software. It does relate to MPI as described here. https://docs.abinit.org/tutorial/basepar/ Anyway, I'll change it.

Comment: The `openmpi` tag is to be used when the issue is specific to Open MPI (e.g. `abinit` built with `MPICH` or its derivative works fine). Otherwise, the appropriate tag is `MPI`